# Is scala import recursive?

Tags: scala, import

With

```
import mypack._
```

do I still need to

```
import mypack.box.writer
import mypack.box.reader
```

and

```
import mypack.box.parser.stringparser
```

?

And what's the proper keyword to search/google? "Recursive" gives me overwhelming "tail recursion" results.

Comment: "Recursive" seems irrelevant here. "Subsuming," perhaps or conceivably "transitive." In any event, as Daniel answers, it has no second-tier or deeper importing effects. Another thing it doesn't do is add anything to the externally visible contents of a name space (including when the import appears inside a type or value definition block).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, Scala import is not recursive.

Packages are there to keep the namespace in the current scope clean. Importing all subpackages by default would go against that.

On the other hand, imports are relative, so you can do this:

```
import mypack._
import box.writer
import box.reader
import box.parser.stringparser
```

Some people dislike this style, as it is somewhat error-prone. I dislike it because there's no clear distinction between absolute and relative imports. Still, it helps sometimes.