# not found value index error on elastic4s

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

im trying to index some data to elastic search by using the   [elastic4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s) API

but im getting compile error  `not found: value index`

this is the code , later on i will map the js object fields  to the elastic search fields , 
**but for now i just want to index a test case**

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s._
def indexComment(commentList: List[JsObject]) {
val client = ElasticClient.local
for (comment <- commentList) {
   val id = comment.\("id").as[String]   
   client.execute {
     index into "posts/test" id id.toString() fields (
      "name" -> "London",
      "country" -> "United Kingdom",
      "continent" -> "Europe",
      "status" -> "Awesome")
    }

   }

   }

  }
```

and this is the SBT file

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      jdbc,
     anorm,
     cache,
    "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.1",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.0",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.0-1",
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s" % "1.0.0.0"

)`

and this is the complete error

`[error] /home/mik/programing/posts/app/helper/Helper.scala:27: not found: value index
[error]          index into "posts/test" id id.toString() fields (
[error]          ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Feb 15, 2014 1:34:54 PM`

did i miss something in the installation process ??

or it`s something else ??

thanks miki

Comment: It looks like `index` is undefined as an identifier, but hard to say why specifically. Please post the **entire** relevant snippet and the **complete error**.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato  hi i added the complete error

Comment: We still need more code to tell you how to solve your problem.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato i posted the complete method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is a missing import. As the documentation you linked [states](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s#introduction), **you also need the following:**

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticDsl._
```

The [`ElasticDsl` module](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s) is an "entry point" for elastic4s' [DSLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), including the [`IndexDsl`](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/IndexDsl.scala) from where the `index` and `into` methods that you use come from.

**The aforementioned import is necessary in addition to the one you do have because in Scala [import statements are not recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552956/is-scala-import-recursive?rq=1).**