# Scala Elastic4s can't find indexInto method

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

I've been looking to integrate elastic search into my Scala program, but it consistently has trouble finding certain methods and values. In this case, it cannot find indexTo and the '/' in the string as mentioned by the stack trace. I think it is a problem with the imports but I am still new to the language. Any help is appreciated!

Stack Trace:

```
[error] /Users/khalid/prog/decision_tree/src/main/scala/IrisClassifier2.scala:60:13: not found: value indexInto
[error]             indexInto("myindex" / "mytype").fields("s_length" -> (Json.parse(n) \ "sipJson" \ "s_length").as[Double],
[error]             ^
[error] /Users/khalid/prog/decision_tree/src/main/scala/IrisClassifier2.scala:60:33: value / is not a member of String
[error]             indexInto("myindex" / "mytype").fields("s_length" -> (Json.parse(n) \ "sipJson" \ "s_length").as[Double],
[error]                                 ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Main code inside object where code is failing:

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticsearchClientUri
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.HttpClient
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.search.SearchResponse
import org.elasticsearch.action.support.WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticDsl

val client = HttpClient(ElasticsearchClientUri("localhost", 9200))

client.execute {
        indexInto("myindex" / "mytype").fields("s_length" -> (Json.parse(n) \ "sipJson" \ "s_length").as[Double],
                                                 "s_width" -> (Json.parse(n) \ "sipJson" \ "s_width").as[Double],
                                                 "p_length" -> (Json.parse(n) \ "sipJson" \ "p_length").as[Double],
                                                 "p_width" -> (Json.parse(n) \ "sipJson" \ "p_width").as[Double],
                                                 "result" -> labelMap(model.predict(input)))
        .refresh(RefreshPolicy.WAIT_UNTIL)
    }.await
```

Build.sbt file:

```
name := "SparkDT"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"
val elastic4sVersion = "5.6.5"

dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.7",
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-core" % elastic4sVersion,
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-http" % elastic4sVersion,
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-streams" % "5.6.5",
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-testkit" % elastic4sVersion % "test",
  "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s-embedded" % elastic4sVersion % "test"
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not found value index error on elastic4s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797007/not-found-value-index-error-on-elastic4s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer was simple and I just overlooked it. Change this import statement:

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticDsl
```

To:

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.ElasticDsl._
```