# No execution context even when I have import ExecutionContex.global

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I have import `import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._`

```
val lock1 = lock(tweet)
val lock2 = lock(tweet)
for {
  r1 <- lock1
  r2 <- lock2
} yield r1 -> r2
```

but this block complains

```
Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext, either require one yourself or import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
[error]         r2 <- lock2
[error]            ^
```

Comment: What is `t2`? I only see `r2` in your block. What is the return type of `lock`? Where is your import compared to your block? Same object? Same package?

Comment: @vptheron that's `r2`, the `lock` function returns a Future[Boolean]. The import statement is at the first of the file. By the way I am writing this in a `spec2` specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` import this works fine. But I don't know why

Comment: [Because it's not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552956/is-scala-import-recursive).